# evaluating array expressions

Tags: arrays, z3

I'm using Z3-3.2's c-api (on linux) for solving QF_AUFBV problems.

If the formula is satisfiable, I'd like to read out the value of the free array variables from the model.

I tried something along the lines of the following code and I'd like to know if the general idea of how to do this is right:

```
void evaluate(Z3_context context, Z3_model model, Z3_ast array)
{
  Z3_ast value;
  Z3_bool success = Z3_eval(context, model, array, &value);
  if (success) {
    unsigned num_entries;
    if (Z3_is_array_value(context, model, value, &num_entries)) {
      Z3_ast indices[num_entries];
      Z3_ast values[num_entries];
      Z3_ast def;
      Z3_get_array_value(context, model, array, num_entries, indices, values, &def);

      // do something with indices, values, and def
    }
  }
}
```

The input Z3_ast array is definitely a free array expression. Z3_eval returns true, so  we seem to have successfully evaluated the expression, but then Z3_is_array_value returns false. I would have expected the result of a successfull Z3_eval on an array expression to be an array value, so why is this not the case?

By the way: We managed to get at the desired information by iterating over all model_func_decls and trying to find the right one for that array by comparing their get_symbol_string. So the information seems to be available somewhere in Z3, but that hardly counts as a nice solution.

Thanks for any help on this.

Best regards,
 Florian

Answer (score 0):

The evaluator is a bit more powerful than the API for accessing array values.
The function is_array_value succeeds only when the represented array is of the form
(store (store (store (... (const v) ...) ..)..))
or of the form as-array[f], where f is a finite unary function.

The is_array_value and get_array_value functions can be implemented using the existing API
and are exposed for convenience
(as you describe, except we can avoid using string comparisons and instead use comparisons on
the function declarations that are enumeration sorts).
So it sounds like we would be able to support more in your case and I am curious how the model value
looks like. Would you be able to provide additional information about the example that does not pass? (print it?)

Thanks